# Code to Populate Combobox with the change in Value of Textbox

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have one worksheet in which 2 tables are there.

One table is grouphead and the other table is controlhead.

In grouphead table, there are several unique records along with their ID. Like Non-current assets has a id NCA, Current Assets has a ID CA and so on.
In controlhead table, there are several unique records along with grouphead id. Like Salman and Amir has id NCA and Abdur Rehman and Rahim has id CA.

When i open the userform, the grouphead combobox populates with grouphead and the groupcode id textbox shows the id of item selected in combobox.

There is another combobox named as controlhead.
What i want is, the controlhead combobox will populate only those values which have id present in grouphead textbox.

so far my code is as below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim start As String
    Dim start2 As String
    Dim sfind As String
    Dim sfind2 As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tbl2 As ListObject

    Set ws = Sheets("Summary of Accounts")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("grouphead")
    Set tbl2 = ws.ListObjects("controlhead")

    With Me
        If .ComboBox1.Value <> vbNullString Then
            sfind = .ComboBox1.Value
            start = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sfind, tbl.DataBodyRange, 2, False)
                .TextBox1 = start
        End If
    End With

    With Me
        If .TextBox1.Value <> vbNullString Then
            sfind2 = .TextBox1.Value
            start2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sfind2, tbl2.DataBodyRange, 2, False)
            .ComboBox2 = start2
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I am unable to populate the controlhead combobox.

Kindly review and help me.

Comment: It is pretty easy actually but before I post an answer, can you show your screenshot of the tables so that I can check the code before postin git

Comment: i have posted the image of tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Sample Data**

[image]

**Logic For code**

1. Add the table 1 items to combobox1
2. In the click event of 1st combobox, populate the textbox and the 2nd combobox

**In Action**

[image]

**Code**

```
Dim tblGH As ListObject
Dim tblCH As ListObject

'~~> Populate combobox1 in userform init event
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Summary of Accounts")

    Set tblGH = ws.ListObjects("grouphead")
    Set tblCH = ws.ListObjects("controlhead")

    For i = 1 To tblGH.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        ComboBox1.AddItem tblGH.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub

'~~> The click event
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Dim r As Long

    r = ComboBox1.ListIndex

    If r = -1 Then Exit Sub

    '~~> Add to txtbox
    TextBox1.Text = tblGH.DataBodyRange.Cells(r + 1, 2)

    '~~> Add to 2nd Combo
    PopulateCombo
End Sub

Sub PopulateCombo()
    ComboBox2.Clear

    For i = 1 To tblCH.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If tblCH.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1) = TextBox1.Text Then _
        ComboBox2.AddItem tblCH.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2)
    Next
End Sub
```